# Specify Lookup list for the 'Title' Column of a Gantt chart view

Tags: 2010, list-view, lookup-column, gantt-view

I was hoping to use a lookup list as the title column for a Gantt chart view. The problem is when I go to the Gantt columns in the settings for the view it doesn't display any of the lookup list columns as available options.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new column for the lookup field, then set the Title column's value to the lookup field's value using a small workflow in SharePoint Designer.